# How many 3 letter words possible with the word Abacus?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I am having difficulty solving this. I know that 6 letter words possible with abacus is (6! / 2! ).
But my doubt is what happens when we have to choose 3 letters from abacus and how will we handle the repeating of the double a.

Comment: How many such words have no $a's$?  How many have exactly $1$?  How many have $2$?

Comment: Hint: how many words don't use $a$ at all? How many use one $a$?...

Comment: This fits in Puzzling SE as well...

Comment: I suppose you have to go by trial and error as, for instance, *aba* and *cas* aren't words.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire One can assume that `word` is to be understood in the mathematical sense, since this was indeed posted on MSE.

Comment: "words", @Simplifire, mean three -character expressions in combinatorics. So indeed, aba and cas, and aus, etc, are all valid "words".

Comment: @amWhy If you type in the initial of the name you want to quote just after the @, it will display the full name and then you just have to click on it, easy and typo-free :)

Comment: Why not just... count them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

1. How many three-letter words can you make with no $a$'s?
2. How many with exactly one $a$?
3. How many with both $a$'s?

These are disjoint sets so you can add them up.